# Setting workbook as a global variable - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I have the below code which enables users to select workbooks to open. I wish to target these workbooks later in the automation through a global variable throughout the automation however I am faced with a subscript out of range when I try to do this.

Please see the below code:

```
Dim FnameAndPath As Variant
Dim ATMFNameAndPath As Variant

Sub GetUserToSelectFile()

MsgBox "Please select the daily reconciliation file"

FnameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If FnameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FnameAndPath

MsgBox "Please select the file with the correct ATM details on"

ATMFNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select ATM File To Be Opened")
If ATMFNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ATMFNameAndPath

ans = MsgBox("Please confirm the below is correct" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " BankRec Filelocation = " & FnameAndPath & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " ATM File location = " & ATMFNameAndPath, vbYesNo, "Confirmation correct files selected")

If ans = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "The macro will abort"
    MsgBox FnameAndPath
    Workbooks(FnameAndPath).Close    'ERROR Line
    Workbooks(ATMFNameAndPath).Close 'Error Line
        End
    End If

End Sub
```

Please can someone advise how I can target the workbooks in later automations - The error currently appears when I try to close the workbooks.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you close a workbook, then a variable cannot refer to it any more. Try putting the workbook's full path in a string so that other macros can open it.

Comment: Don't include the path when closing the workbook, or store the workbook reference in a global variable rather than the file name & path. `Dim wrkbk As Workbook` and then `Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Open(FNameAndPath)`  and then `wrkbk.Close`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a workbook you need to specify the full path to the file (or accept the current default path) - so   FnameAndPath is just that. But when you refer to a specific open workbook using Workbooks(name) - you should only supply the name, not the full path.
try this   Instead of

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FnameAndPath
```

Try

```
    Dim wbRecFile as Workbook
    Set wbRecFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FnameAndPath)  'note brackets
```

and then you can do

```
    sbRecFile.Close
```

Comment: I guess, **w**bRecFile

Comment: Whoops! yes - fingers too big for the keyboard